# First time updating a running NGINX web server

Tags: nginx, update

So, NGINX 1.13.2 was released today, and I'd like to update my 1.13.1 installation.  I can't simply use something like `$ apt-get install nginx` because I'm using a few static modules in my build.  Due to that, I have a few questions:

1. Should I overwrite the existing files completely?  I originally extracted NGINX itself to `/opt/nginx` so should I just `$ tar -xvzf nginx-1.13.2 -C /opt/nginx`?
2. I'm guessing I'll need to run `./configure` again with the same values as before.  When I run `make` should I use `$ make upgrade` rather than `$ make install`?
3. Is there anything else I should be aware of?  I know about using the `USR2` and `WINCH` signals to gracefully shutdown the old master process and start the new one, but I'm assuming that's after steps 1 and 2.  Anything more I should know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should uncompress the new nginx tarball to a new directory, then reconfigure with your *configure* string with the same values as before. I usually run first *make*, then *make install*

This will overwrite the nginx files from your last version. You have to stop it for a second, usually it's best to do something like

```
systemctl stop nginx && make install && systemctl start nginx
```

Comment: Which files are overwritten?  In a virtual host setup, do I need to backup my site.conf files, and then reload them?

Comment: Your existing configuration won't be overwritten. I've tested with newer nginx and it's ok. As far as I can remember I had once an issue with overwritting with nginx 0.7. I usually backup anyway.